# Kendo UI Chart giving errors while building in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have a Kendo UI Line chart that fetch and display information form a backend endpoint.  The chart has 3 buttons that fetch information for 3 time ranges, 7 days, 30 days and 365 days. The HTML and JS code is given bellow.

**HTML**

```
<div style="text-align: right">
            <div class="a-item" style="padding: 1em">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="timeFrame" ng-click="changeTimeframe(7)" btn-radio="7" translate>Week</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="timeFrame" ng-click="changeTimeframe(30)" btn-radio="30" translate>Month</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="timeFrame" ng-click="changeTimeframe(365)" btn-radio="365" translate>Year</label>
                </div>
                <div kendo-chart k-options="authChart" id="authChart" style="height: 266px;"></div>
                <div class="auth-chart-loading"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.changeTimeframe = time => {
                    $scope.timeFrame = time;
                    kendo.ui.progress($(".auth-chart-loading"), true);
                    if ($("#authChart").data('kendoChart') && $("#authChart").data('kendoChart').options) {
                        if (time === 7) {
                            $("#authChart").data("kendoChart").options.categoryAxis.baseUnit = "days";
                        }
                        if (time === 30) {
                            $("#authChart").data("kendoChart").options.categoryAxis.baseUnit = "weeks";
                        }
                        if (time === 365) {
                            $("#authChart").data("kendoChart").options.categoryAxis.baseUnit = "months";
                            $("#authChart").data("kendoChart").options.categoryAxis.labels = { dateFormats: { months:"M/yy"} };
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.authAttempts.read();
                };

                $scope.authAttempts = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/api/reporting/SuccessfulAuthenticationAttempts",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: () => { return { TimeFrame: $scope.timeFrame } }
                        }
                    },
                    sort: {
                        field: "Date",
                        dir: "asc"
                    }
                });

                $scope.authChart = {
                    dataSource: $scope.authAttempts,
                    legend: {
                        position: "bottom"
                    },
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        type: "line",
                        style: "smooth",
                        tooltip: {
                            visible: true
                        }
                    },
                    series: [
                        {
                            field: "Field 1",
                            name: "FIELD 1",
                            aggregate: "sum",
                        }, {
                            field: "Field 2",
                            name: "FIELD 2",
                            aggregate: "sum",
                        }],
                    categoryAxis: {
                        field: "Date",
                        baseUnit: "days",
                        type: "date"
                    },
                    valueAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            template: (obj) => {
                                return removeDoubleLabels(obj.value);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    render: e => {
                        // Clear up the loading indicator for this chart
                        kendo.ui.progress($(".auth-chart-loading", e.sender.element.parent()), false);
                    }
                };
```

In visual studio the above implementation gives build errors with

> Property 'baseUnit' does not exist on type 'ChartCategoryAxisItem[]'

but when running the app, it works fine and when the buttons are clicked the charts updates without any issue. After the build error i changed the implementation to the following..

```
$scope.changeTimeframe = time => {
                    $scope.timeFrame = time;
                    kendo.ui.progress($(".auth-chart-loading"), true);
                    if ($("#authChart").data('kendoChart') && $("#authChart").data('kendoChart').options) {
                        if (time === 7) {
                            $("#authChart").data("kendoChart").options.categoryAxis[0].baseUnit = "days";
                        }
                        if (time === 30) {
                            $("#authChart").data("kendoChart").options.categoryAxis[0].baseUnit = "weeks";
                        }
                        if (time === 365) {
                            $("#authChart").data("kendoChart").options.categoryAxis[0].baseUnit = "months";
                            $("#authChart").data("kendoChart").options.categoryAxis[0].labels = { dateFormats: { months:"M/yy"} };
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.authAttempts.read();
                };
```

I changed the categoryAxis to be an array and then the build issues were gone. But when running the app, when i click the button to update the chart to 30 days or 1 year, the following console error pops up and the chart hangs.

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'baseUnit' of undefined

The version of the Kendo UI library that we are using is **2014.3.1119** and we are using `TypeScript` in script files. My development environment has Visual Studio 2015 and TypeScript version 1.6. The Visual studio project files included th TypeScriptTools version of 1.0. I updated it to 1.6 but did not work. I also tried updating the typescript definitions files for kendo UI as well. But that failed too.

What can i do to get this issue fixed. Do i need to update the Kendo UI lib to the latest version. Or is there something else.

What should i do to get this issue fixed.